# UITableViewController doesn't have navigation bar when pushed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I'm using this code

```
-(void)gotoInformationViewController:(id)sender
{
    MoreViewController *moreViewController = [[MoreViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:moreViewController animated:YES];
    [moreViewController release];
}
```

to push a `MoreViewController` (which is `UITableViewController`) but it doesn't have `UINavigationBar` when pushed, just `UITableView` on whole screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try  this in your view Controllers

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

and make sure in interface builder your viewcontroller's top bar is not set to none

Comment: I'll check too if self.navigationController != nil

Comment: @DiegoFreniche you don't have to